# Faster way to Unix cd by changing one directory inside path?

Tags: shell, unix

I have multiple directories (eg tom richard harry) that have identical subdirectory and file structure. If I am working on a file inside one directory, is there a fast or easy way to cd to the equivalent path in another directory?

Example

```
pwd=/mystuff/myproject/tom/hobbies/sports/highschool

cd /mystuff/myproject/richard/hobbies/sports/highschool
```

I was hoping for some shortcut like cd pwd but change tom > richard in one command.

Comment: Not really, you can maybe create an alias to do so.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use tcsh. I ended up using tcsh equivalent(?) to solution from @WilQu.
`cd ${PWD:s/tom/richard}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should work:

```
cd ${PWD/tom/richard}
```

Comment: short, simple, convenient and easy to remember. Thanks for the tip, if I could I'd vote twice for it :-)

Comment: Much better than the `awk` script I was just writing, though if you use awk, you don't have to know you're already in `tom` directory...

Comment: +1 That'll work too. I forgot about that. Works in both Korn and BASH.

Comment: Here's the AWK-enhanced version: `cd ${PWD/`pwd | awk -F'\/' '{ print $4 }'`/richard}` ... anyone know how to escape backticks which should be around `pwd ... awk` pipeline?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Use `$()` instead?

Comment: @Daenyth the command works, but stackoverflow is hiding the backticks that are embedded in the command...

Comment: @PaulProgrammer sure it works, but the `$()` is generally preferred wherever possible.

Comment: This worked great in bash, but since I use tcsh, I had to experiment to find the equivalent sub with s:

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

`cd $(pwd | perl -pi -e 's/tom/richard/g;')`

Comment: I had to do something like this to get it to work in a c-shell alias.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what directory you're in (say stored in `$dirname` variable):

```
function dirswitch() {
    newdir="$1"    
    cd $(pwd | sed -e "s#/$dirname/#/$newdir/#")
}
```

This should handle the job in bash. So if you're in `dirname=tom` and you want to switch to `harry`:

```
dirswitch harry
```

...will do the trick.

Comment: Everyone should be upvoting @WilQu's answer. It's much better. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's history expansion for this.

`^tom^richard` - this will rerun the previous command, substituting `richard` for `tom`.

[Bash History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)

Comment: I forgot about this method. It works great, even in tcsh, if I type out cd "fullpath". But if I do cd $PWD, it doesn't seem to be able to expand the env var out.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends upon your shell...

Most people use BASH -- it's the standard Linux shell, but Kornshell is very similar to BASH, and has the feature you're looking for:

```
$ cd /mystuff/myproject/tom/hobbies/sports/highschool
$ cd tom richard
$ pwd
/mystuff/myproject/richard/hobbies/sports/highschool
```

I also like the Kornshell `print` command and the way variables in Kornshell don't disappear on you in loops (because BASH makes them child processes).

Of course, BASH has features that are missing in Kornshell. One example is setting your prompt. In Bash, I set my prompt as thus:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\n\$ "
```

- `\u` is the user ID
- `\h` is the short host name
- `\w` is the working directory in relationship to `$HOME`
- `\n` is the newline
- `\$` is a `$` if your ID isn't root and `#` if your ID is root.

The Kornshell equivalent is:

PS1=$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")

As I said, they're mostly equivalent. I can work with either one, but Kornshell has this particular feature and BASH doesn't.

Your alternative is to write a function that will do this for you, or to make an alias to the `cd` command.

Answer (score 0):

Some shells, such as [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) and ksh offer a special form of the `cd` builtin:

```
cd [ -qsLP ] old new

  The second form of cd substitutes the string new for the string old in the
  name of the  current  directory, and tries to change to this new directory.
```

So if you are using `zsh` or `ksh`, then this command should do it:

```
cd /mystuff/myproject/tom /mystuff/myproject/richard
```

no matter which subdirectory of `/mystuff/myproject/tom` you happen to currently be in.